# Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds. Required 892413000000000 and got: 0

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am trying to deploy a solidity contract using web3 and nodejs and I get an error on all testnets: 
If I try to run on the local testrpc, everything works fine. 
Can you spot any error in the code that might cause this error, or is there an issue with the testnets?

[image]

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
var Web3 = require('web3');

// Infura test network (kovan)
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://kovan.infura.io/v3/3e0f68cb39c64417b15cf55e486479dd'));
var myAddress = '0x362aa2Bf4b6fB733C4EF41F4d2833E8e5aDc54ed';
var myPrivateKey = new Buffer('a288c7c873f09e96b7f0e404759288606e2ffc0edf58874aeb5a0fe4bcd9c262', 'hex')

// Compile contract from file
const contractPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'HDS.sol');
const contractSourceCode = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, 'UTF-8');
const compiledContract = solc.compile(contractSourceCode, 1).contracts[':HDS']
var newContractAddress = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(web3.utils.randomHex(20));

// Create a transaction
var rawTx = {
    from: myAddress,
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex('13'),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1', 'gwei')),
    gas: web3.utils.toHex('892413'),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex('892413'),
    data: compiledContract.bytecode
};

// // Unlock account to sign transaction
// web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(myAddress, myPrivateKey, 600)
// .then(console.log('Account unlocked!'))
// .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });

web3.eth.getBalance(myAddress)
.then(function(balance) { console.log("My balance: ", balance); })
.catch(function(error)  { console.log(error); });

web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTx, myPrivateKey)
.then(function(signResult) {    
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signResult.rawTransaction)
    .on('error', function (error) { console.log("Error deploying contract: " + error); })
    .on('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) { console.log("Transaction hash: " + transactionHash); })
    .on('receipt', function (receipt) { console.log("Receipt contract address: " + receipt.contractAddress); })
    .on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {     
        console.log("Confirmation number: " + confirmationNumber);
        console.log("Confirmation receipt: " + receipt);
    })
    .catch(function (error) { console.log(error); });
});
```

Here's the account on Kovan testnet, if it helps: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x362aa2bf4b6fb733c4ef41f4d2833e8e5adc54ed

Comment: It looks like you're expecting Infura to be able to sign the transaction for you, but it doesn't know your private key. (You're probably getting a "405 Method Not Allowed" status back from the HTTP request.)

Comment: Your URL also looks wrong to me. What's the "v3" about?

Comment: "When you sign up you'll receive your Infura v3 key to use within your app..."  - https://infura.io/docs
Do you have any resource or documentation that states that testrpc does not need signed transactions, opposed to testnets which do? How would my code change to send signed transactions compared to the way I'm currently doing it?

Comment: I don't have a documentation link handy, but it's correct that `ganache` (formerly `testrpc`), like most node software, stores private keys and can sign transactions with them. Infura, being a public node, isn't a safe place to store your private key, and thus they don't support handling it. Your code would need to sign the transaction with the appropriate private key and then use `sendSignedTransaction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sign the transaction before you send it to the network. The easiest way to do this would be to unlock one account using your mnemonic. You can do this when you initialize `web3` and using `truffle-hdwallet-provider`, after that you can send transaction from your account without the need to manually sign them, in my opinion this is the easiest way to do this. Another option is to manually sign each transaction before you send it using your private key, you can read [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction) how you can do this. There is no difference in terms of functionality between the two ways but the first on is a little bit easier if you are new to this.

Comment: By signing the transaction, I was able to get a transaction hash, which unfortunately can't be found in blockchain explorer "Sorry, We Are Unable To Locate This transaction Hash". I have transasctions from yesterday with same status. Any ideas?

Comment: Signing the transaction is the first step. After signing it you also have to actually send the transaction to the network. The object that you get after signing the transaction contains a field named `rawTransaction`. This is what you want to send to the network using `sendSignedTransaction`, the documentation of which is here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendsignedtransaction . This process is also explained in the return type section of `signTransaction`. The `receipt` event of `sendTransaction` means that the transaction has completed.

Comment: Also, this is not present in the example provided in the documentation but should probably listen for the `error` event in addition to the receipt event so you know if something went wrong, meaning the transaction reverted(out of gas, require that failed inside the contract, etc.). To listen for this event use: `.on("error", error => {console.error(error);});` after the `receipt` event.

Comment: I got passed that error with the tips you mentioned (signing transaction). Now I get a new error - Error: Returned error: Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds. Required 892413000892413 and got: 0 - Account clearly has enough eth to sign the transaction. Any thoughts?

Comment: First of all make sure you are connected on the correct network(mainet, rinkeby, kovan etc.) and that the account has funds in that network, the error message says it got 0 ether. If it is none of the above then maybe you have made something else wrong that causes this error. One thing could be that you did not sign the transaction correctly. If none of this is the case then it is the first time i see this error.

Comment: I edited my question and pasted full code, including credentials on the testnet, so you can maybe reproduce the full scenario. Thanks for the help! "HDS.sol" is a simple contract written in solidity and located on my disk.

Comment: I am not sure if what you are doing is the correct way to deploy a contract. Try to follow the instruction here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy , on how to deploy.Personally i prefer using 'truffle-hdwallet-provider' as it unlocks the account and makes things simpler, unless it is not suitable for what you are trying to do.